# Trying to create saving feature for highscore IOS Spritekit (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am currently working on a game for IOS with the "sprite kit" provided by Xcode. After doing some research it appears some people use NSUserDefaults as a way to do this. I tried to incorperate this method into my code by doing it this way....

```
// Store the score
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setInteger:self.score: forKey:@"score"];

// Get the score 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSInteger *retrievedScore  = [defaults integerForKey:@"score"];
```

This doesn't work though and gives me an error. Am I doing something wrong? do I need to implement something? is there another method I should be aware of?

P.S. This is my first question so please go easy on me, if needed I can provide additional information just ask...
Thanks :)

EDIT: The Error I get when I implement the storing/saving code:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSUserDefaults'
```

When I implement the loading code I don't get an error as such but it does come up as a warning. I'm not sure if the code works either as I haven't been able to save some data and then attempt to retrieve it with this loading method.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @puddinman13 I have added the warnings in an edit :)